# iOS Google maps giving error

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my App it is possible to tap an button and then in the Google maps app it shows the route from your current location to the destination. It was working till some internal data structures changed and now it is not ;)

The error I get is:

```
Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 8.)"
```

Which I looked up in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010237-CH2-SW2) means (I think):

```
kCLErrorGeocodeFoundNoResult
The geocode request yielded no result.
Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
Declared in CLError.h.
```

Currently this is my code: (I'm using hardcoded location for testing right now):

```
+ (void) showRouteInMapsFromCurrentToLocation:(NSString *) location{
    Class mapItemClass = [MKMapItem class];
    if (mapItemClass && [mapItemClass   respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)]){
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:@"Kardingerweg 48, Groningen"
                 completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                     if(!error){
                                                 CLPlacemark *geocodedPlacemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                        MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc]
                                           initWithCoordinate:geocodedPlacemark.location.coordinate
                                           addressDictionary:geocodedPlacemark.addressDictionary];

                        if(placemark && geocodedPlacemark){
                            MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
                            [mapItem setName:geocodedPlacemark.name];
                            NSDictionary *launchOptions = @{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving};
                            MKMapItem *currentLocationMapItem = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];
                            [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:@[currentLocationMapItem, mapItem] launchOptions:launchOptions];
                     }
                     }else{
                         NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
                     }
                 }];
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer of Viruss mca, I now have the correct form which is:

```
Kardingerweg 48, NL-2165 VS Groningen
```

Answer (score 1):

Error Code 8 is "**kCLErrorGeocodeFoundNoResult**", so I suspect you're searching for something with no results,

You are searching for 'Kardingerweg 48, Groningen' it is also not searching in apple map, try with different location.**'Kardingerweg,Groningen'**.

Comment: This is limitation of it.

Comment: Not true I found it ;) : Kardingerweg 48, NL-2165 VS Groningen  is a correct form